# TBody not working on table with Jquery DataTable

Tags: asp.net-mvc, datatables

I am using JQuery Data Table in my project.

I have ActionResult and getting data. I want to display data in table but if I use tbody, datatable is not styling look like normal table.

I tried without data and wrote custom tbody and tr tags. My probiem is continue. Where is my wrong ?

**ActionResult**

```
 public ActionResult YayinEvleri()
        {
            dbContext = new DatabaseContext();
            var yayinEvleri = dbContext.YayinEvi.ToList();

            return View(yayinEvleri);
        }
```

**View**

```
@model List<KitapFuari.Models.Yayinevi>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js "></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready( function () {
    $('#yayinEvleri').DataTable();
    });
    </script>
 <table id="yayinEvleri" class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%" cellspacing="0">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Yayın Evi</th>
                    <th>Yazar</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              @foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>@item.Ad</td>
                    </tr>

                }
            </tbody>

        </table>
```

Comment: please read https://datatables.net for use datatable in your code

Comment: I looked this page. I used datatable before.

Answer (score 0):

Add this script.

```
$(document).ready( function () {
$('#yayinEvleri').DataTable();
});
```

Comment: I have already this. Please read carefully my post. My problem isn't about first loading. When I use tbody, datatable style lost.

Comment: you need two td tag as you 've two th.

Comment: I tried 2 td tags. Same problem. Sorry for my English :)